# Maths on PHP Timestamps

Tags: php

I have the following block of PHP:

```
if ($data->timestamp > (time() - 10 * 60) ) {
 // data is newer than 10 mins
} else {
 // data is older than 10 mins
}
```

That basically says if the timestamp stored in `$data` is older than 10 minutes.

I'm not sure how this is worked out exactly, and I've read about the time function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

I want to edit it to become **every hour** instead of 10 minutes.

Can anyone share some advice/resources? e.g. how I would change it to become 1 hour and how exactly this is worked out.

Comment: Look into [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). This site has lots of examples of what you;re doing that use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code line checks if the timestamp saved in the $data is NOT older than 10 minutes.

the time() function gives UNIX tiemstamp of the machine in seconds. If you want to change it to an hour its 60 minutes in 60 seconds 60*60. Your code will be like this:

if ($data->timestamp > (time() - 60*60) )

Answer (score 1):

it is worked out starting from the right to left in seconds. One hour would be

```
if ($data->timestamp > (time() - 60 * 60);
```

Formatt

```
time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
// 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60secs
```

You are multiplying it as you work back 60 multiplied by 60 minutes etc etc

Comment: Didn't you mean `if ($data->timestamp > (time() - 60 * 60);`?